# How to create columns in a data frame with the name of the object repeated using code that doesn't require manual input

Tags: r, automation, annotations

I want to know how to create columns in a data frame with the name of the object repeated using code that doesn't require manual input.

For example, I can do this manually using the following code:

```
# displays df
mtcars

# adds column manually
# ---- NOTE: REQUIRES MANUAL INPUT
mtcars$dataset_name <- c("mtcars")

# gives unique values for mtcars$dataset_name
unique(mtcars$dataset_name)
```

Is there anyway to do this automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: Not necessarily right now. I can use the following code to add this to a list, but I'm not sure how to do this for individual datasets:
```
tidybayes_construction_df <- 
  Map(function(x, y) 
    data.frame(x, object_name = y,
               check.names = FALSE), tidybayes_construction_df, names(tidybayes_construction_df))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a function that takes a object as input, and returns a column with the object name

```
f1 <- function(dat) {
        nm1 <- deparse(substitute(dat))
        dat$dataset_name <- nm1
        dat
  }
f1(mtcars)
```